# Can I add a message to NUnit assertion using PostSharp

Tags: nunit, postsharp

How can I change my Assert statement behaviour from:

`Assert.That(User.HasOrderInvoice, Is.True)`

to

`Assert.That(User.HasOrderInvoice, Is.True, "Assert.That(User.HasOrderInvoice, Is.True)")`

using PostSharp.

I know that `Fody` has an addin `AssertMessage.Fody` that can do this. I use PostSharp and I am not able to figure this out. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that with PostSharp (you would need an add-in, but PostSharp's add-in API is not documented and not supported).

Comment: Not directly, but is there workaround by may be intercepting `Assert.That()` call